# How to display dynamic data in Material-UI table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I have API that returns some tabular data. I need to display these data in a Table. It's not clear to me how to achieve this goal.

Let's assume that I want to display the fields `id` and `name` stored in `groups`. How can I show them in the Material-UI Table?

Please see my current code below. It does not throw any error. But neither is shows a Table with the data.

```
import '../../App.css';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '../../config/config.json';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(18),
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
    },
    content: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
        textAlign: "left",
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit*3,
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit*3,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit*3
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 650,
    },
    tableheader: {
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
        color: "#ffffff",
        background: "#3f51b5"
    },
    tableCell: {
        background: "#f50057"
    },
    button: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        minWidth: 100
    },
}));


export function Main() {

    const [groups, setGroup] = React.useState('');

    const classes = useStyles();

    const options = {
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(config.api.url + '/api/test', options)
            .then( (groups) => {
                this.setState({response: groups})
            })
            .catch( (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>

            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.content}>
                    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                        <Table id="split_table" size="small">
                            <TableHead>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>
                                {Object.keys(groups).map( (row, index) => (
                                    <TableRow key={index} selected="false">
                                        <TableCell>Test</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Test</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>))}
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>

                </Grid>    
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Update:**

As I mentioned in comments, I followed the recommendations from answers, but I still see an empty table, while I can see a correct value in console.

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(config.api.url + '/api/test', options)
            .then( (groups) => {
                setGroup(groups.data.subtask)
                console.log(groups.data.subtask);
            })
            .catch( (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>

            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.content}>
                    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                        <Table id="split_table" size="small">
                            <TableHead>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>
                                    {Object.keys(groups).map( (item, index) => (
                                    <TableRow key={index} selected="false">
                                        <TableCell>{item.user_id}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>{item.task_name}</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>))}
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>

                </Grid>    
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
```

This is what I see in the browser:

[image]

This is an example of data (`groups.data.subtask`):

[image]

Comment: Use setGroup(groups) instead of this.setState({response: groups})

Comment: I think a problem is here setGroup(groups.data.subtask[0]). Try to write it so setGroup(groups.data.subtask)

Comment: @AlexAV-dev: I tried it. It does not work.

Comment: @AlexAV-dev: Please see my last update where I posted an example of `groups.data.subtask` as you requested.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. The problem was that you gave us the wrong keys of objects

Comment: @AlexAV-dev: Sorry for this confusion. In my code I always used `user_id` and `task_name`. So, it's not the issue. The keys are correct. But still the Table is empty. As I said, I see correct data in Console when I do: `console.log(groups.data.subtask[0].user_id)`. So, it's not the issue of keys.

Comment: Try replacing <TableCell> with <div>, will it be also emty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219281/discussion-between-alexav-dev-and-fluxy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the `Object.keys(groups)` .

It's not React state, so it will not re-render?

Can you try to make a groupKey state and then useEffect to update the state when groups is updated.

```
const [groupKey,setGroupKey] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setGroupKey(Object.keys(groups));
},[groups]);
```

In the component , use

```
{groupKey.map((item, index) => (
  <TableRow key={index} selected="false">
    <TableCell>{item.user_id}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>{item.task_name}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>))
}
```

You get the idea.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer? what do you mean by "groupKey state"? any example would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: react will render only if it's state is changed. Object.keys() will give out a new array which is not a react state. so it will not re-render? just a suggestion.

Comment: I think you are right. But I don't understand some aspects of your example. What is `[groups]`?

Comment: @Fluxy it's the dependencies of useEffect. useEffect will accept two parameter.. a function to do side effect and an array of dependencies.. when the dependencies change, the function is executed again.

Comment: You need to replace initial value string with array [groupKey,setGroupKey] = useState([]);

Comment: I did so. Anyway now it works. I wrote `setGroupKey(groups.data.subtask)` and I used `[ ]` instead of `[groups]`. The rest is the same as you showed.

Comment: ohh yea, sorry i typed it fast and didnt' check..so groups.data.subtask is the real data for groups ? :D i thought it was groups lol...anyway, well done to make it work ... high-five!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you use `this.setState` instead of `setGroup`

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(config.api.url + '/api/test', options)
        .then( (groups) => {
            setGroup(groups)
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}, [])
```

Change your map function

```
{Object.keys(groups).map( (row, index) => (
  <TableRow key={index} selected="false">
    <TableCell>{row._id}</TableCell>
    <TableCell>{row.user_id}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>))}

import '../../App.css';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '../../config/config.json';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(18),
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
    },
    content: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
        textAlign: "left",
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit*3,
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit*3,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit*3
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 650,
    },
    tableheader: {
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
        color: "#ffffff",
        background: "#3f51b5"
    },
    tableCell: {
        background: "#f50057"
    },
    button: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        minWidth: 100
    },
}));


export function Main() {

    const [groups, setGroup] = React.useState([]);

    const classes = useStyles();

    const options = {
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
        }
    }

useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(config.api.url + '/api/test', options)
            .then( (groups) => {
                setGroup(groups.data.subtask)
                console.log(groups.data.subtask);
            })
            .catch( (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }, [])

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

        <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.content}>
                <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                    <Table id="split_table" size="small">
                        <TableHead>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                                {Object.keys(groups).map( (item, index) => (
                                <TableRow key={index} selected="false">
                                    <TableCell>{item.user_id}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{item.task_name}</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>

            </Grid>    
        </Grid>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: not only using `setState`, he is using `this.setState({response: groups})` (setting `response` state, not `groups` state).

Comment: @yaya I think it is not a problem because we anyway save response in state group. I can be wrong if it is so, please explain me why i'm do not right :)

Comment: doesn't `this.setState({response: groups})` sets the value of `groups` variable to `response` state?

Comment: Thanks. Now I can see the table. But the content of this table is still wrong because I think that my code inside `<Table>...</Table>` is wrong. I see `Test` in all cells of the Table instead of a real data.

Comment: @Fluxy yeah you should replace `<TableCell>Test</TableCell>` with `<TableCell>{row.yourcolname}</TableCell>`

Comment: Thanks. Now I see the empty table. But I checked logs as follows to see what is happening: `setGroup(groups.data.subtask)`          `console.log(groups.data.subtask[0].id);`. This code displays a correct number in console. I do not understand why `{row.id}` inside `<Table>...</Table>` shows nothing.

Comment: Can you add groups.data.subtask in your question? I will try to help with it

Comment: @AlexAV-dev: Done.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should help:
[image]

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: groups.map is not a function`.